# Cant toggle between two jquery/ajax forms without page reloading after first ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an ajax form structured in the following way:

```
<% if @post.saved? %>
   <%= render 'shared/unsave' %>
<% else %>
   <%= render 'shared/save' %>
<% end %>
```

In application.js (both are the same):

```
$(document).ready(function (){  
   $('.save_form').submit(function (){  
   $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), null, "script");  
   return false;  
 });  
});

$(document).ready(function (){  
   $('.unsave_form').submit(function (){  
   $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), null, "script");  
   return false;  
 });  
});
```

The forms work properly when clicked once, but reload the page when clicked a second time. Why cant I toggle between the two forms with ajax?

shared/save partial:

```
<%= form_for current_user.saved.build(:post_id=> post.id), :html => { :class => 'save_form'}, :remote => true do |f| %> 
            <div><%= f.hidden_field :post_id %></div>
            <%= image_submit_tag("save-off.png", :alt => "save", :id => "save_button", :title => "Add to Saved") %>
 <% end %>
```

shared/unsave partial:

```
 <%= form_for current_user.saved.find_by_post_id(post), :html => { :method => :delete,  :class => 'unsave_form' }, :remote => true do |f| %> 
            <div><%= f.hidden_field :post_id %></div>
            <%= image_submit_tag("save-on.png", :alt => "unsave", :id => "unsave_button", :title => "Remove from Saved") %> 
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Difficult to tell without seeing the HTML, but a few potential problems: 1. You're completely replacing the form as a result of the AJAX call, thereby removing the submit event handler. 2. Your "unsave" form doesn't have class `save_form`, so attempting to bind the event handler doesn't work.

Comment: Hey Anthony, I know this a bit delayed but what exactly do you mean. How could one prevent the form from being completely replaced by the ajax call? My unsave/save form have to have two classes(both save and unsave)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe include `preventDefault()`?  You also don't need to define the ready method twice:

```
$(document).ready(function (){ 

   $('.save_form').submit(function(event){  
      event.preventDefault();
      $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), null, "script");  
      return false;  
   });  

   $('.unsave_form').submit(function(event){  
      event.preventDefault();
      $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), null, "script");  
      return false;  
   }); 

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that but, unfortunately, it didnt work.